# request for member which is of pointer type (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)

Tags: c++, pointers

I have the following error on my code :

```
request for member 'affiche' in 'px', which is of pointer type 'Exemplaire*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)
```

The error is located on this line :

```
*px.affiche();
```

But I have the same kind of error on these lines:

```
if(*px.getOeuvre().getLanguage() == langue) {
*px.affiche();
```

Here is the line where `px` pointers are generated :

```
Exemplaire* px(new Exemplaire(oeuvre));
```

Here is the full `Bibliotheque` class :

```
class Bibliotheque {
    private:
    string nom;
    vector<Exemplaire*> collection = {};

    public:
    Bibliotheque(string nom)
    : nom(nom) {
        cout << "La bibliothèque " << nom << " est ouverte !" << endl;
    }
    string getNom() const { return nom; }
    void stocker(Oeuvre& oeuvre, unsigned int n = 1) {
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            Exemplaire* px(new Exemplaire(oeuvre));
            collection.push_back(px);
        }
    }
    void lister_exemplaires(string langue = "") {
        if(langue == "") {
            for (auto px: collection) {
                *px.affiche();
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
        else {
            for (auto px: collection) {
                if(*px.getOeuvre().getLanguage() == langue) {
                    *px.affiche();
                    cout << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I tought I could access the pointed variable of `px` by using the operator `*`...
Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: yes, `px` is a pointer, so you need `px->member` or `(*px).member`. Parantheses are important, because `.` has precedence over `*`.

Comment: *px.pInt would dereference the pointer pInt, not px.  (*px).pInt would dereference the pointer px, not pInt.  *(*px).pInt would dereference both.